# New Ubuntu user, and I can't change the directory in the terminal

Tags: command-line, 13.10

I have been a Windows user all my life. I just switched to Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander) on one of my laptops. It's neat and all, but I'm having difficulty with the terminal.

I am trying to install Komodo Edit, but I don't understand it. I'm using this site "http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.0/install.html#Installing_Komodo_on_Linux" the terminal will not let me change my directory.

I have the Komodo Edit file in Home/Downloads/KEEP/applications/Komodo Edit. Whenever I try to cd to anywhere besides home it says 'no such file or directory'.

That is my current problem, but I also barely understand the terminal, as well as how to download/install applications using ppa. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you typing all the UPPER and lower cases just as the name are? In Ubuntu KEEP Keep keep keep are for different folders.

Comment: yes!

I was using cd /Home/Downloads etc.. That wasn't working and I just found to use cd ~/Downloads/KEEP/applications which seems to work, but how to I do a folder with spaces in it?

I'm a little confused. When I use the command pwd, it says my directory is /home/myusername. But if I open the files, there is no 'myusername' in /home, just Desktop, Documents, Music, etc... Anyways, that's not the main problem.

Comment: `~/` is a shortcut command to the Home folder directory of the user logged in via the Terminal session. The absolute path to a user Home folder would be `/home/username/`. To enter a directory that has spaces in the name, you can either escape the spaces with a `\ ` or enclose the portion of the path with quotes: `cd ~/Documents/My\ Stuff` or `cd ~/Documents/"My Stuff"`

Answer (score 0):

It is sometimes a good idea before changing directory to type `ls` first to list the contents of your current location so that you know the exact name of the directory you want to change to. I say this because typing `cd Komodo-<version>-<platform>` will probably not get you to the location as you need to edit it for the specific version and platform you have unpacked. When you `cd` to another location try just typing the first few characters of the next directory you want to go to then hit tab which should autocomplete the statement for you, this will prevent any missed characters or typos that may be causing you issue.

An easier way to install this package though would be with `apt-get`

Run the following commands and it should do the install for you.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mystic-mirage/komodo-edit
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install komodo-edit
```

Comment: I have actually done the apt-get, I don't understand it though, where do I find Komodo Edit if I've done that?

Comment: Did you do all three commands? During the apt-get install were you prompted that a package was going to be installed. It may also say that other packages will be installed along with it if it has dependencies with other packages. Go into Ubuntu Software Centre and verify that the package is there and installed. If it is installed you should be able to start it with the following command in terminal 'komodo [options] [filenames]'

Comment: I did all three commands, when I search in Ubuntu Software Centre it shows up. Do I use that command exactly? I'm not sure what [options] or [filenames] should be replaced with.

Comment: No you would not type [options] & [filenames] they get replaced you can read the manual for komodo or get some basic usages by usually typing komodo --help. So that we can check is this is installed or not, can you copy and paste the output from the following command 'dpkg -s komodo' please? (Remove the quotes from around the command...)

Comment: I'm not sure what I did, but I got it working, I appreciate all your help!